# How to Query A DataGridView Using Linq

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that I want to query using Linq (C# WinForm). I want to "count" rows where a certain criteria is met. For example,

```
variable1 = "count rows where ColumnBoxAge > 3 || < 5"

label1.Text = variable1
```

How to do this in C# WinForm using Linq?

Comment: What do you have as a DataSource in your DataGridView?

Comment: i have a dataset from a SQL Server stored proc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it could work but you can try this;

```
dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Field<int>("ageColumn") > 3 ||
     c.Field<int>("ageColumn") < 5).Count();
```

Edit : Where instead of Select.

Comment: it's counting all rows in the dgv...not what I want. Shld be "count rows where BoxAge is between 3 and 5"...

Answer (score 0):

So your query is wrong! Try to put '&&' instead of '||';

```
dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Field<int>("ageColumn") > 3 &&
     c.Field<int>("ageColumn") < 5).Count();
```

Edit : Where instead of Select.

Answer (score 0):

@yapiskan

```
dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Field<int>("ageColumn") > 3 &&
     c.Field<int>("ageColumn") < 5).Count();
```

.Where instead of .Select

Thank you very much! I appreciate your help.